# Azure incremental load (delta load) pipeline from Oracle server to Azure data lake (CSV)

Tags: azure-data-lake

I have a issue that Create a pipeline get data from oracle on premise server to azure data lake with incremental load(delta load).

I did one pipeline for copy activity to get full load of table from oracle to data lake (csv). now I am creating another pipeline to get new rows from oracle table and append in previous data lake CSV.
I created lookup activity to get data by Queary but I don't know to add data in Main CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the watermark logic and make it happen this in one pipeline .
This article should be helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-delta-copy-with-control-table